# Comparing old and new picklist values in workflow

Tags: apex, workflow

i am working on picklist which has values as  5%,10%,15% and 20%.
I want to send a email when picklist value is greater than last picklist value .
Like we have picklist value 5% and thsi time user selects 10% so email will be send .
I have studies abut priorvaue and ischanged but still confused how to make a perfect formua.

Comment: add your code, what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your picklist values are of numerical type then I guess in your workflow you can do something like this

```
 AND(
   IsChanged(Field__c),
   PRIORVALUE(Field__c) < (Field__c ), 
   )
```

Other wise you would need to evaluate all the cases such as:

```
 OR(
     AND(
       IsChanged(Field__c),
       isPickVal(PRIORVALUE(Field__c),"5%"),
       OR( isPickVal(Field__c,"10%" ), isPickVal(Field__c,"15%"),isPickVal(Field__c,"20%" ))
       ),
     AND(
       IsChanged(Field__c),
       isPickVal(PRIORVALUE(Field__c),"10%"),
       OR( isPickVal(Field__c,"15%" ), isPickVal(Field__c,"20%"))
       ),
      AND(
       IsChanged(Field__c),
       isPickVal(PRIORVALUE(Field__c),"15%"),
       isPickVal(Field__c,"20%" )
       )
     )
```